# Python 3: Calling a function from its class to simulate a switch statement not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that is a simulation game of a variant on the rock paper scissors game.  In my main function I am outputting a interface and then trying to call a method defined within that acts as a switch statement.  I am getting: "makeSel() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'" TypeErrors I have scoured the web for any hints yet cannot find any that have helped.  I have tried to change "makeSel()" to "Main.makeSel()" but it just gives me that main is undefined.

---

```
class Main:

    def makeSel(self):
        selection = input()
        if(selection == 1):
            return StupidBot('StupidBot')
        elif(selection == 2):
            return RandomBot('RandomBot')
        elif(selection == 3):
            return IterativeBot('IterativeBot')
        elif(selection == 4):
            return LastPlayBot('LastPlayBot')
        elif(selection == 5):
            return MyBot('MyBot')
        elif(selection == 6):
            return HumanPlayer('HumanPlayer')
        else:
            print('Invalid selection, please try again.  Enter 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6')
            makeSel()

    print('')
    print('Welcome to my Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock game!')
    print('')
    print('Please select two players, enter 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6')
    print('  (1) -> StupidBot')
    print('  (2) -> RandomBot')
    print('  (3) -> IterativeBot')
    print('  (4) -> LastPlayBot')
    print('  (5) -> MyBot')
    print('  (6) -> HumanPlayer')

    p1 = makeSel()
    p2 = makeSel()
```

---

I was hoping that someone would be able to shed some light on the issue I am experiencing.

Comment: The immediate problem is that `input` returns a string - so you need to convert that to an `int` as such - `selection = int(input())`

Comment: That parentheses around the `if` condition are very unpythonic. Please just use `if a == b:`.

Comment: Someone else try to fix what would normally be the obvious editing on this - someone's beeped around with my editor settings

Comment: You're also spelling `selection` wrong a few times...

Comment: @DavidRobinson ty - have put the main tag back though

Comment: @Jon Clements Thanks for noticing the two misspellings of selection.  I have fixed them in my normal code. and in the code posted on the forum

Comment: @HunterOehrtman you do actually also have class instances of the bot? Because if all it does is change their name - this seems a pretty big waste of time in the sense that it's easier to do it otherwise - but I'm taking this is a learning exercise, so probably best not to pursue that

Comment: @Jon Clements: Yes each bot is its own class instance with behaviors of each bot.

Comment: @HunterOehrtman any reason it needs to give its own name again to itself and not have anything more?

Comment: @Jon Clements: each bot is a subclass of a superclass Player, only the play() of each bot is different.  The name is passed into the function to give each bot its own name.

Comment: But each bot knows its own name anyway (or whould so anyway) - so....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the immediate but, change `makeSel()` to `self.makeSel()`.  `self` isn't implicitly passed to method calls in Python, unlike some other languages.  You also mean `return self.makeSel()`, I think.

Also, I think you want a loop in `mainSel()`.  You're recursively calling `mainSel()` which work a lot like a loop but will fill up the call stack.

```
class Main:

    def makeSel(self):
        while True
            selection = input()
            if(slection == 1):
                return StupidBot('StupidBot')
            elif(slection == 2):
                return RandomBot('RandomBot')
            elif(selection == 3):
                return IterativeBot('IterativeBot')
            elif(selection == 4):
                return LastPlayBot('LastPlayBot')
            elif(selection == 5):
                return MyBot('MyBot')
            elif(selection == 6):
                return HumanPlayer('HumanPlayer')
            else:
                print('Invalid selection, please try again.  Enter 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6')
```

Comment: When i do this, I just get "NameError: name 'self' is not defined"

Comment: @HunterOehrtman: Are you sure your code is as you show it here? (Since you misspell selection in the first `if` statement, I'm not sure how it can be).

Comment: @HunterOehrtman: Oh, the issue is in the last two lines, which were apparently lost in one of the edits. You need to create an object like `m = Main()`, and then call `p1 = m.makeSel()` and `p2 = m.makeSel()`.

Comment: @Peter Graham: Yeah, I actually didn't notice that misspelling in the first statement.  Thank you for catching that for me.  It also was in the first elif, tying to type to fast I suppose.  However I haven't been able get into the function in the first place.

Comment: @HunterOehrtman: Beyond that, it's unclear whether you indented the `print` statements to be included in `class Main`. They should all be unindented.